# Python / BeautifulSoup - findAll tags which text endswith regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract from a sitemap only particular links that ends with the pattern "`video-[1-9]+\/`".

**sitemap**

```
<urlset>
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/i-dont-want-this/</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/i-want-this-video-5/</loc>
</url>
</urlset>
```

**Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = BeautifulSoup(sitemap, 'lxml')
links = data.findAll('loc', text = re.compile(...))
print links
>> [<loc>http://www.example.com/i-want-this-video-5/</loc>]
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is the problem? your pattern seems to work fine, may be add an anchor `$` to match the end of string, `video-[1-9]+/$`?

Comment: The problem was matching the end of the string! Thank you!

Comment: @Psidom can you add the answer so I can close the question? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean match at the end of string, you can add an anchor `$` to the pattern, as `video-[1-9]+/$`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<urlset>
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/i-dont-want-this/</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/i-want-this-video-5/</loc>
</url>
</urlset>""", "lxml")

import re
links = soup.findAll('loc', text = re.compile("video-[1-9]+/$"))
links
# [<loc>http://www.example.com/i-want-this-video-5/</loc>]
```